# Print PDF file to network POS printer using Mike42/Escpos-php Library

Tags: php, printing, pos

testing with the provided examples, text can print normally, but it can't print a pdf file nor image file, and there is no any error message i can found,,, please advice !

the following code, commented line is working fine for text printing

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Change to the correct path if you copy this example! */
require __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\ImagickEscposImage;
// use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;

/* Most printers are open on port 9100, so you just need to know the IP 
 * address of your receipt printer, and then fsockopen() it on that port.
 */
$pdf = 'pdf.pdf';
try {
    // $connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("192.168.1.1", 9100);
    $connector = new FilePrintConnector("192.168.1.1", 9100);
    
    /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    // $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
    // $printer -> cut();

    $pages = ImagickEscposImage::loadPdf(__DIR__ . "/". $pdf);
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $printer -> graphics($page);
    }
    
    /* Close printer */
    $printer -> close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: For example, these libraries seem to support PDF to .png conversion in PHP. [spatie/pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image), [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)
There may be others, so why not look for them?

Comment: @K J Did you have any information about using a ZPL printer in his question, including the other two? I think it's an ESCPOS printer if he accepts escpos-php. Then, in the comment of this question, I introduced a library with PDF to .png conversion function. Escpos-php will be responsible for converting .png files to printer image print commands. Instead, if he wants to print to a ZPL printer, he'll probably switch to a library for that.

Comment: By the way, does the PDF page size fit within the printable range of the printer? How about changing the pageWidth parameter of loadPdf()? Other than that, have you tried to see if you can print ordinary graphics data instead of PDF?

Comment: @K J @kunif, Thanks for continue support!  here summaries your suggestion and question,, the converted pdf, jpg, png files with width 72mm for the 80mm thermal printer XP-80C can print out normally on windows. The printer is on list of Escpos-php Library. Regarding to the link-os, it need java virtual machine, is it worth to try....

Comment: ps, using NetworkPrintConnector can print out Hello World! text, But whatever ImagickEscposImage::load or ImagickEscposImage::loadPdf to load a file, it prints out a long mess ascii string. When using FilePrintConnector, there is no respond on the printer, blank page on browser,,,, please help!